# when I run my celery server,the server cursor is blinking before the ready message(Slove)

Tags: django, rabbitmq

I'm having a bizarre problem error when I run my celery it's loading but not giving the ready message if I run any task it is running the function but not giving any success message with seconds, even I have make the function with a print statement to make it come to celery the return inside the function, doesn't come to celery as it should be normally with the success message with
this is my celery.py

```
**from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ontym.settings')
app = Celery('ontym')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()**
```

this is the server my picture
[celery server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2PlH.png)
but it should be like this [Celery server with ready message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBsXA.png)

tasks.py

from celery import shared_task

```
@shared_task
def hello_task(name):
    print("hello from task",name)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzW2T.png)

Comment: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.

Comment: Did you add  these lines in your project __init__.py?                                                                               
proj/proj/__init__.py:
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)}

Comment: yes i do  from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__=('celery_app',)

Comment: @andrewJames I have provided the code its the error message image, that has nothing to do with code

Comment: Please provide anything which is text (such as error messages - and not only code) as formatted text in the question. There are many reasons why it can be very helpful to do this. These reasons are explained in the link in my first comment. Here is just one of those reasons: "_Images cannot be interpreted by screen readers, which is a major usability problem for those with visual impairments._"

Comment: Also, "_the error message image_" that you mention does not actually show any errors. None of the image links in the question show any errors. They only show warnings. What error message are you actually getting? Can you add the error message to the question (as formatted text)? That may make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: there should be a ready message from the celery coming at the end of celery server line which is not coming and celery result with success in second is also not showing , as you can show in the image of result

Comment: @andrewJames  i have add the my celery server and what should be the normal server image have a look please

Comment: its slove , problem was my logger configuration  inside the setting file